# How to skip DRAG_DETECTED Events from TableHeaderRow (resizing TableColumns)

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, resize, tableview, drag

In order to use a `TableView` (with resizable columns) as drag source, 
I have attached an `onDragDetected` handler on that `TableView` with the effect, that resizing `TableColumns` does not work anymore: If the user clicks into the `TableHeaderRow` for dragging the column separators, these mouse events are consumed by my handler too.

The handler is attached to the whole `TableView` and I do not see a way to distinguish between events from `TableRows` and events from the `TableHeaderRow`.

Attaching the handler to the data-rows only is not appropriate in my case, since I need multiline selection (and do not want to have dependencies from the `RowFactory` to the application data model).

Any suggestions?
best Hans

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself: I had to look up the `TableHeaderRow` instance with the `lookup`-method, and discard the DRAG_DETECTED event there.

```
    Pane header = (Pane) mainTableView.lookup("TableHeaderRow");
    header.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("ignoring drag operation from table header.");
            event.consume();
        }
    });
```

After that, resising of table columns works. Maybe there is something wrong with my drag+drop event handling that initially caused the problem!? Somebody voted down without comment...

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Hans does work, but only after the window is shown. I added a window.setOnShown((WindowEvent e) listener and then I was able to do the lookup and header.setOnDragDetected.
Here is how I added it:

```
    window.setOnShown((WindowEvent e) -> {
        Pane header = (Pane) mainTableView.lookup("TableHeaderRow");
        ....
    });
```

Otherwise, lookup returns null.